# How to create RPM package with GitHub repository

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, yum

I'd like to create an RPM package that depends on a github repository.

If I run this command standalone:

```
yum localinstall https://github.com/matthewmueller/giftbox/blob/master/rpm/monit.rpm
```

It'll work just fine. However if I try to make it a dependency of an RPM package (using FPM), it errors out with:

```
--> Processing Dependency: https://github.com/matthewmueller/giftbox/raw/release-2017-08-21-08-33/rpm/monit.rpm for package: giftbox-2017_08_21_08_33-1.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: giftbox-2017_08_21_08_33-1.x86_64 (/giftbox)
           Requires: https://github.com/matthewmueller/giftbox/raw/release-2017-08-21-08-33/rpm/monit.rpm
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Here's the command I'm running to generate the RPM package:

```
@fpm \
        --input-type=dir \
        --output-type=rpm \
        --name $(NAME) \
        --version $(VERSION) \
        --architecture x86_64 \
        --package "$(DIR)/rpm/$(NAME)-$(VERSION).rpm" \
        --rpm-os linux \
        --template-scripts \
        --after-install "$(DIR)/postinstall.sh" \
        --after-upgrade "$(DIR)/postupgrade.sh" \
        --before-remove "$(DIR)/preremove.sh" \
        --depends "procps" \
        --depends "util-linux" \
        --depends "initscripts" \
        --depends "$(GHBASE)/monit.rpm" \
        --force \
            "$(DIR)/init.sh"="/etc/init.d/giftbox"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please try to install packages with --skip-broken. It will excludes packages which are broken. I am not sure but check once.

Comment: I got this: `Packages skipped because of dependency problems: giftbox-2017_08_21_08_33-1.x86_64 from /giftbox` which would suggest that it didn't install the package. FWIW, the package isn't broken, it'll install fine with yum localinstall. it seems localinstall is doing some additional resolution.

Comment: Can you check any dependency for this package is missing by googling it ? Please confirm the version you are trying to install weather is crashing with some other packages.

Comment: sorry, but this isn't a package dependency problem. i'm trying to resolve github links to rpm packages as dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

`Requires: some_package`

can contains only package name.

`yum install http://some.url/some.package.rpm` is just feature of yum, which will download the file and then install. You cannot use URL in requires.

What you can do:
* create rpm called e.g. my-repo.rpm which will contains repo file (`/etc/yum.repos.d`) which will enable the repository where monit.rpm is located
* Then you can put `Requires: monit` to giftbox.
* `yum install my-repo.rpm` and in second step you should be able to do 'yum install giftbox`

Comment: thanks a lot @msuchy. this confirms my assumption and the approach you suggested is what i ended up doing. For others: http://blog.celingest.com/en/2014/09/17/create-your-own-yum-rpm-repository-using-amazon-s3/ & http://tylerpower.io/post/hosting-yum-repo-on-s3/ were helpful for me.